# Extract Multi Values to point error table was not found

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, arcgis-10.4, error-999999, extract

Newbie to arcpy.  Tried using this tool after successfully using Extract Value to Point tool with same data.  I received the correct data appended to the attributes table.  I would like to use the Multi Values tool but I am getting the errors below.  I shortened the files names to avoid character limits but still unsure what this error means.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame

shpFile = "C:/Users/Documents/ArcGIS/data.gdb/shpFile"
file1 = "C:/Users/Documents/ArcGIS/data.gdb/FA290"
file2 = "C:/Users/Documents/ArcGIS/data.gdb/FA300"
arcpy.sa.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(shpFile, [[file1, "FA290"],[file2, "FA300"]], "NONE")
```

Error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
> line 8, in     File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7345, in
> ExtractMultiValuesToPoints     bilinear_interpolate_values)   File
> "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py",
> line 53, in swapper     result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)   File
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7340, in
> Wrapper     bilinear_interpolate_values)   File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
> 506, in      return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
>
> ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. The table was
> not found. [VAT_FA300] Failed to execute (ExtractMultiValuesToPoints).

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug that could correspond to your issue:

[BUG-000096840 - The Extract Multi Values to Points tool fails with "Error 999999" when a 64-bit raster is used as the input in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4 and 10.4.1.](http://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA5Njg0MA==)

It is fixed in ArcGIS 10.5 for Desktop (now available as Beta) and ArcGIS Pro 1.3, you can test the tool in these versions if you have access to them.